# The ship/vessel/boat sails to/in/on the sea/ocean/river

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What are the differences in meaning when using *to*, *in*, or *on* after *sail* in the examples below? Is it possible to use all the collocations with the three prepositions in all the examples?

There's a ship sailing to/in/on the sea.

There's a ship sailing to/in/on the ocean.

There's a boat sailing to/in/on the river.

He is sailing to/in/on the sea/ocean/river.

Comment: I would say "on" for all of them.

Comment: All of them are possible, but they mean different things.  *On* or *in* means that is where the boat is now.  *To* means that is where the boat is headed.  A more specific answer would require more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What are the differences in meaning when using to, in, or on after sail in the examples below?

When you refer to the ship sailing ***to*** a thing, you're describing the sailing object's **goal**.

> There's a ship *sailing to the sea*. It *sailed to the river* upstream and ultimately it's *sailing to the ocean*.

When you refer to the ship sailing ***on*** a thing, you're referencing it's current location on top of said object. For boats, this is a good thing; a ship that's sailing ***in*** a river or ocean has **sunk below the surface**.

> My father's been sailing on Lake Eerie for years. At least until that last storm; now his boat is ***in*** Lake Eerie and he's afraid to go out on the water anymore.

When you use the word **in** you're talking about being contained by or enclosed within something. You can sail *in* a ship *on* the Adriatic, but sailing *on* a ship *in* the Adriatic is only possible in submarines (at least if you wish to survive the experience).

The only way you can use ***in*** with respect to sailing and still make sense is when you're speaking geographically. This is because the *in* now refers to being within the borders of said geographical area.

> My father's been sailing in waters around the Florida Keys for years!

## Is it possible to use these ... in all the examples?

Using **to** or **on** for the examples would work just fine (though your second and third example sentences are missing an article). As stated above, however, using **in** wouldn't make sense unless you were referring to a geographical location (or going down with the ship).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just edited my question to add the missing articles.

Answer (score 2):

As stangdon pointed out context is everything here...

> > There's a ship sailing to the sea.

The ship is in the Atlantic Ocean headed toward the Mediterranean Sea, or perhaps in a river headed toward the sea.

> > There's a ship sailing in the sea.

A submarine is generally thought of as "sailing" underwater so that could be "in" the sea. Also if you're referring to a general area it would make sense to say something like "The SOS is coming from a ship in the the Mediterranean Sea."

> > There's a ship sailing on the sea.

A sailboat generally floats on top, so it sails "on" the sea.